# What are the best practices for calling an external api?

Tags: python, scrapy

So let's say I want to write a spider that using the Facebook API to calculate the likes on every page of a website. If I import the requests library, I'm able to call the Facebook graph API as follows.

```
import scrapy
import json
import requests

API_KEY="KEY_GOES_HERE"

class WebSite(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "website_page"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://website.com/']
    def get_likes(self,url):
      base='https://graph.facebook.com/{}?access_token={}'.format(url,API_KEY)
      data=requests.get(base)
      return self.parse_likes(data)
    def parse_likes(self, data):
      data = json.loads(data.text)
      return data['id'],data['share']['comment_count'],data['share']['share_count']

    def parse(self, response):
        item= {}
        item['url'] = response.url
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        item['fb_url'],item['shares'],item['comments'] = self.get_likes(response.url)
        for link in links: 
          link = response.urljoin(link)
          item['link'] = link
          yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse)
        yield item
```

However, I can't seem to get this code to work if, rather than using the requests, I use the scrapy.Request call. Something like this.

```
import scrapy
import json
import requests

API_KEY="KEY_GOES_HERE"

class WebSite(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "website_page"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://website.com/']
    def get_likes(self,url):
      base='https://graph.facebook.com/{}?access_token={}'.format(url,API_KEY)
      return scrapy.Request(base,callback=self.parse_likes)
    def parse_likes(self, data):
      data = json.loads(data.text)
      return data['id'],data['share']['comment_count'],data['share']['share_count']

    def parse(self, response):
        item= {}
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['fb_data']=self.get_likes(response.url).body
        for link in links: 
          link = response.urljoin(link)
          item['link'] = link
          yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse)
        yield item
```

In this case, I just get a blank response for the Facebook data. I think i'm missing some understanding about how the scrapy.Request method works relative to the standard requests library. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common case: How to yield from item from multiple urls?
And the most common solution is to chain requests by carrying your item in `request.meta` paramater.

For your example implementation with this logic could look like:

```
class WebSite(scrapy.Spider):
    base='https://graph.facebook.com/{}?access_token={}'.format
    api_key = '1234'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links: 
            item= {}
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['fb_data']=self.get_likes(response.url).body
            item['link'] = response.urljoin(link)
            api_url = self.base(self.api_key, link)
            yield scrapy.Request(api_url,
                                 callback=self.parse_likes, 
                                 meta={'item': item})

    def parse_likes(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        data = json.loads(data.text)
        share_count = data['id'],data['share']['comment_count'],data['share']['share_count']
        item['share_count'] = share_count
        yield item
```

Comment: So I've gotten this working? One quick follow up. If want to call multiple APIS, should I have a chain from parse_likes to parse_tweets to etc or is there some way to do the API requests in parallel?

Comment: Chain itself is not concurrent since every link requires a previous one to finish, however that is not an issue for concurrency since the rest of the spider is concurrent. So if you are crawling 20 websites all chains will be asynchronious from each other but synchronious in themselves. There are no straight-forward ways to have a concurrent chain and usually end up not worth the implementation hassle, but if you are interested you should look into pipelines and how to schedule requests in them.